# How to add prefix/suffix on a repeatable dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, on-duplicate-key

Could you please suggest is there any way to keep all the repeatable (duplicate) keys by adding prefix or suffix.  In the below example, the address key is duplicated 3 times.  It may vary (1 to 3 times).
I want to get the output as in the expected output with adding a suffix to make the key unique.
Currently the update function is overwriting the key value.

```
list = ['name:John','age:25','Address:Chicago','Address:Phoenix','Address:Washington','email:John@email.com']
dic = {}
for i in list:
    j=i.split(':')
    dic.update({j[0]:j[1]})
print(dic)
```

Current output:
{'name': 'John', 'age': '25', 'Address': 'Washington', 'email': 'John@email.com'}

Expected output:
{'name': 'John', 'age': '25', 'Address1': 'Chicago', 'Address2': 'Phoenix', 'Address3': 'Washington', 'email': 'John@email.com'}

Tried the below:

```
list = ['name:John','age:25','Address:Chicago','Address:Phoenix','Address:Washington','email:John@email.com']
dic = {}
for i in list:
    j=i.split(':')
    dic.update({j[0]:j[1]})
print(dic)
```

Expected output:
{'name': 'John', 'age': '25', 'Address1': 'Chicago', 'Address2': 'Phoenix', 'Address3': 'Washington', 'email': 'John@email.com'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
list_ = ['name:John','age:25','Address:Chicago','Address:Phoenix','Address:Washington','email:John@email.com']

dic = {}
for i in list_:
    j = i.split(':')
    key_ = j[0]
    count = 0 # counts the number of duplicates
    while key_ in dic:
        count += 1
        key_ = j[0] + str(count)
    dic[key_] = j[1]
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'John',
 'age': '25',
 'Address': 'Chicago',
 'Address1': 'Phoenix',
 'Address2': 'Washington',
 'email': 'John@email.com'}
```

PS. don't use the python keyword `list` to name your variables as it overrides the type `list`

Comment: This keeps the duplicate keys, but the 1st one is not suffixed.

Comment: Ooh I misread, didn't notice 1st one needs to be suffixed as well.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `list` as a variable name. `list` is the name of a Python builtin class, and it is used in the following solution. I renamed your list variable `l`.

This solution consists of first building a *multidict* (using collections.defaultdict(list)) to store the multiple values:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for entry in l:
    key, value = entry.split(':', 2)
    d[key].append(value)
```

now `d` contains:

{'name': ['John'], 'age': ['25'], 'Address': ['Chicago', 'Phoenix', 'Washington'], 'email': ['John@email.com']}

then iterate the values of `d`, and if more than one, append a suffix:

```
output = {}
for key, values in d.items():
    if len(values) > 1:
        for i, value in enumerate(values):
            output[f'{key}{i+1}'] = value
    else:
        output[key] = values[0]
```

output:

{'name': 'John', 'age': '25', 'Address1': 'Chicago', 'Address2': 'Phoenix', 'Address3': 'Washington', 'email': 'John@email.com'}

Comment: This is what I would do as well. Note one can use `setdefault()` here and avoid the import by defining `d = {}` then `d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`. Of course, I assume you know that and I'm just noting it for other future viewers

Comment: @JonSG: true, but I find `defaultdict` a tad more readable; and in this specific example, I felt that mentioning the `list` type was a valuable teaching example :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution (this iterates over the list only once):

```py
lst = [
    "name:John",
    "age:25",
    "Address:Chicago",
    "Address:Phoenix",
    "Address:Washington",
    "email:John@email.com",
]

cnts, out = {}, {}
for k, v in map(lambda s: s.split(":"), lst):
    c = cnts.get(k, 0)
    if c == 0:
        out[k] = v
    elif c == 1:
        out[f"{k}1"] = out.pop(k)
        out[f"{k}2"] = v
    else:
        out[f"{k}{c + 1}"] = v

    cnts[k] = c + 1

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": "25",
    "Address1": "Chicago",
    "Address2": "Phoenix",
    "Address3": "Washington",
    "email": "John@email.com",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first separate values from keys in two lists, then make the keys list unique by adding suffixes and combine the unique keys with the values into a dictionary at the end:

```
data = ['name:John','age:25','Address:Chicago',
        'Address:Phoenix','Address:Washington','email:John@email.com']

keys,values = zip(*(s.split(":") for s in data))
keys        = [ k+str(keys[:i].count(k))*(keys.count(k)>1) 
                for i,k in enumerate(keys,1) ]
dic         = dict(zip(keys,values))

print(dic)

{'name': 'John', 
 'age': '25', 
 'Address1': 'Chicago', 
 'Address2': 'Phoenix', 
 'Address3': 'Washington', 
 'email': 'John@email.com'}
```

*Note that this does not cover cases where the suffixed keys clash with original keys.  For example: ["Address1:...","Address:...","Address:..."] would produce a duplicate "Address1" by adding a suffix to the "Address" key.  If that situation could exist in your data, a different approach would be needed*

Alternatively, you can use a dictionary to group values in lists associated with each key and then expand this group dictionary to produce distinct keys:

```
grp = dict()
grp.update( (k,grp.get(k,[])+[v]) for s in data for k,v in [s.split(":")] )
dic = { k+str(i or ''):v for k,g in grp.items() 
                         for i,v in enumerate(g,len(g)>1) }

print(dic)

{'name': 'John', 
 'age': '25', 
 'Address1': 'Chicago', 
 'Address2': 'Phoenix', 
 'Address3': 'Washington', 
 'email': 'John@email.com'}
```

Although `grp` itself may actually be easier to manipulate in subsequent code:

```
print(grp)

{'name':    ['John'], 
 'age':     ['25'], 
 'Address': ['Chicago', 'Phoenix', 'Washington'], 
 'email':   ['John@email.com']}
```